# Differentiate between stores in Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, store, reducers

I'm working on a project where I want data to be stored separated (although in a single redux store). Assuming I want to differentiate the data, is the following idea considered an anti-pattern?

Action:

```
export const GET_DATA = 'GET_DATA';

export const getData = () => { 
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const data = await axios.get('/data');
      return onSuccess(data.data.response);
    } catch (err) {
      return onError(err);
    }

    function onSuccess(data) {
      dispatch({ type: 'GET_DATA', data });
    }
    function onError(error) {
      dispatch({ type: 'ERROR', error });
    }
  }
}
```

Reducer:

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actionTypes';

const initialState = {
  data: [],
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.GET_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.data
      }
    default:
      return state;  
  }
};
```

Now I want to separate `data` into `data0` and `data1` (s. Action). I thought about adding another property to the second argument, which gets passed to the reducer, e.g. turning:

```
function onSuccess(clients) {
  dispatch({ type: 'GET_DATA', data });
}
```

into

```
function onSuccess(clients) {
  dispatch({ type: 'GET_DATA', data, classification: data0 });
}
```

This would allow me to rewrite my Reducer into:

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actionTypes';

const initialState = {
  data0: [],
  data1: []
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.GET_DATA:
      switch (action.classification) {
        case 'data0':
          return {
              ...state,
              data: action.data
          }
        case 'data1':
          return {
            // ...
          }
    }
    default:
      return state;  
  }
};
```

However I'm unsure if this is considered an anti-pattern? Could you share your thoughts on this or recommend another (better) solution? As an alternative I currently see writing a lot of actions...e.g. `GET_DATA_DATA0`, `GET_DATA_DATA1`...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would consider this a very unmaintainable and an unclear way to do anything in the future.

For each different type of data you have you want to make a new reducer. On my personal project I have a `user`, `conversations`, and `chat` reducer.

Sometimes having small functions seems silly and pointless until you start scaling and are like okay what changed that and how do I follow exactly what happened.

I have an initialState.js file that I use to populate the initial reducer state, which helps make it clearer where data is for new developers.

```
export default {
   chat: {
     id: null,
     messages: [],
   },
   conversations: [],
   user: {
      id: null,
      name: '',
   }
}
```

Each reducer now makes it very clear when dispatching an action what occurred and what data is being updated

So for the chatReducer it would look like

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actionTypes';

import initialState from '../store/initialState.js'

export default (state = initialState.chat, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.RECEIVED_NEW_MESSAGE:
      return { ...state, messages: [...state.message, action.newMessage]}
    case actionTypes.FETCHED_CHAT_SUCCESS:
      return action.chat
    default:
      return state;  
  }
};
```

The last thing I would leave you with is consider testing and what is easier to test and how tests will give you confidence in refactoring down the road.

Comment: Depending on how big initialState gets, you may consider splitting it up - one initialState for each reducer. Instead of importing initialState and using initialState.chat, you would just have an initialState object inside the chat reducer, another inside the conversation reducer, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your input. You wrote: 'For each different type of data you have you want to make a new reducer so for my application I have a user, conversations, and chat reducer.'. Right, but in this case (I have to say, I shouldn't call it 'data' in my examples) the data type is the same, e.g. a tool which can monitor different systems. Each system has the same data (storages, services, etc.), however I still have to differentiatet between them.

Comment: Sorry grammar is not my strongest suit >.< Does this make sense though? @Faizy

Comment: @twils0 is right. Having a single `initialState` file for multiple reducers feels like asking for trouble. As a general principle, chopping things up into the smallest possible pieces, while tedious at the outset, really pays off when the app scales and you're trying to debug.

Comment: @223seneca and twils0 Thanks for the feedback, I will keep it in mind as my apps continue to get bigger. Can you expand on why you feel like this is asking for trouble? Just curious as I haven't had it bite me yet and prefer to stop bad patterns if there is a better pattern.

Comment: For one thing, if there is some problem with how the state is structured you're going to get many different things failing at once if you use the same state for all of them. On the other hand, if you have an individual `initialState`, you have a single point of failure, making it easing to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @223seneca Any other reasons? I guess I have found that stopping my application with an error that the state is incorrectly structured is fine for me because I know that I just changed my initialState and I know where to look for the issue / the ide helps stop/find those issues.

Comment: I mean, that's just my opinion. Do what you feel is best. For what it's worth, from what I recall, all of the demos I've looked at in depth by devs far more experienced in Redux than I am use separate `initialState`s. Also, I'm currently developing an app where the different `initialState`s are both fairly large and unrelated to other parts of the app, so that is probably affecting my instincts here as well.

Comment: TallPaul, @223seneca It’s all about modularity. There are more than a few articles out there about how to structure redux files to scale well. It’s more of an art than a science in certain ways. When you’re talking about hundreds of reducers, you don’t want to search for the reducer file, add something to it, then search for the initialState file, which is probably thousands of lines of code, scroll through it for a while to find the part relevant to the reducer you’ve just modified, and then finally modify that part of initialState state. It’s easier to put the relevant part in the reducer.

Comment: @twils0 That is an excellent explanation and elucidates the practices I’ve adopted without clearly thinking through my reasons for doing so.

Comment: @223seneca thanks. You said about the same thing above. I can’t take too much credit. I just read a lot of articles when I first started out and realized there were a lot of files to organize haha.

Comment: 223seneca and @twils0 thanks for the explanation, most of my projects have not gotten into hundreds of reducers so probably haven't hit that scaling issue yet